# Having problems running Atom text editor on Debian Linux 9.0

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, debian, atom-editor

I'm trying to install Atom to write Python scripts on Debian Linux 9.0. After following the installation procedure, which displayed no errors, when I start Atom all I see is a black window with the title Welcome - /home/Python - Atom, but nothing else happens. If I click around it takes me to their web site https://atom.io.

So I deleted and re-installed again, this time using the debian package atom-amd64.deb. After installing it (dpkg -i atom-amd64.deb) not a single error is displayed, but when I run it I get the same problem, a black screen and nothing else. I also tried to install atom in Lubuntu 17.04 zesty but I got same problem.

Any help to get this editor running would be appreciated.

Comment: Well it's better suited for http://askubuntu.com

Answer (score 0):

**Try this, I hope it will help you as it has helped me**

1. wget https://atom.io/download/deb -O atom.deb
2. sudo dpkg -i atom.deb
3. sudo apt-get -f install